# How to animate with SwiftUI inside UIKit (UIHostingControllers)

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am using two `UIHostingController`s with SwiftUI views, presenting one of them modally using `.present(...)`.
In my SwiftUI view hierarchy of both of the **rootViews** of the UIHostingControllers there is one subview that **I want to animate "into" each other**, i.e. transition one frame over the other when dismissing the modal viewcontroller.

---

Option 1: In pure SwiftUI, this could easily be done using `matchedGeometryEffect`, however this does not work since they are not part of the same view, both have their own `UIHostingController` that they are part of.

Option 2: In pure UiKit, this could be done implementing a `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` and `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`. However, in order to animate, one would need the `UIViews` and their frame and use something like `UIView.animateKeyframes(...)`.

How can this be accomplished in above described case? In my understanding one cannot access the subviews of a SwiftUI view using something like `view.subviews...`. Could I implement some sort of modifier to add to the relevant SwiftUI subviews to expose them to UiKit? If so, how can this be done?

**How else can one implement custom transitions / animations between views inside different `UIHostingControllers`?**

---

UIHostingControllers code:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController, ViewController {
    
    weak var viewModel: MyViewModel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "background")
    }
    
    func setup() {
        let myView = MyView(viewModel: self.viewModel)
        let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: myView)
        addChild(vc)
        vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(vc.view)
        vc.didMove(toParent: self)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            vc.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            vc.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
            vc.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            vc.view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

In some other part of the code I call:

```swift
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
navigationController.present(viewController, animated: true)
```

And the incomplete code for the custom transition:

```swift
class ShrinkDismissAnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.6
    }
    
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        guard let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from),
              let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to),
              let fromVCStatusCapture = fromVC as? MyViewController,
              let imageView = fromVCStatusCapture.view.subviews.first(where: { $0 is Image }) // <- HERE! this doesn't work, how can I access a SwiftUI subview ???
        else {
            return
        }
        // ...
        UIView.animateKeyframes(
            withDuration: duration,
            delay: 0,
            options: .calculationModeCubic,
            animations: {
        // ...
        })
     }
}

class ShrinkDismissTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController)
    -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        guard let _ = dismissed as? MyViewController else {
            return nil
        }
        return ShrinkDismissAnimationController()
    }
}
```

Comment: I imagine this is a problem that will occur more and more as people start to switch to SwiftUI, but not change the entire navigation and structure of their apps as well...

Comment: One possibility I see is to create something like a SwiftUI modifier that wraps a SwiftUI view into a `UIViewRepresentable` to expose the view to UIKit. [This article could help](https://dev.to/gualtierofr/take-screenshots-of-swiftui-views-2h8n)